# How to reduce the speed of RotateAnimation in Android

Tags: android, android-animation, rotateanimation, linear-interpolation

How can I reduce the rotation speed of RotateAnimation instance. I'm using following code snippet to do animation.

```
rotateAnimation = new RotateAnimation(currentRotation, currentRotation + (360 * 5), Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f, Animation.RELATIVE_TO_SELF, 0.5f);
currentRotation = (currentRotation + (360 * 5));
rotateAnimation.setDuration(10000);
rotateAnimation.setInterpolator(new LinearInterpolator());
rotateAnimation.setRepeatCount(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setRepeatMode(Animation.INFINITE);
rotateAnimation.setFillEnabled(true);
rotateAnimation.setFillAfter(true);
rotateAnimation.setAnimationListener(animationInListener);
recordRingImageView.startAnimation(rotateAnimation);
```

Comment: **Reduce Speed = Increase Duration**. Thus, increase the 10000 duration.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Increase its duration since speed = distance/time

```
rotateAnimation.setDuration(30000);
```

Comment: Thanks. I thought setDuration() giving the time of rotation.

Answer (score 1):

Just increase the duration of the animation.
The duration is the time to execute the animation, so if you increase the duration, the animation will take more time to complete, or in other words - the speed of the animation will decrease.